# ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, qt4

This is the code that i'm trying to run:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    return app.exec();
}
```

And this is the error that i'm getting:

```
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[image: Id returned 1 exit status]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the error message carefully, you will see the problem.

> ...ld.exe: cannot open output file ...

The linker is trying to write the generated executable file (`debug.exe`) to disk, but is not allowed to (`Permission denied`). This is mostly due to the fact that the application you built is currently running.

Close it and rebuild the application.

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the application before rebuilding it.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you're running out of disc space.