# Calling a C function from within a function in a .mm file

Tags: objective-c, c

This is one of those problems that is a bit vague and so difficult to pinpoint the cause. I'll try to keep it simple.

I've created a C class with a header like this:

```
C_Class.h

void do_something(void);

C_Class.c

void do_something(void)
{
}
```

Then I have a .mm file that was working perfectly fine until within one of its functions I added my C sub_routine which I created earlier:

```
  #import "C_Class.h" // included in the .h file 


 // then in the .mm file

 - (void)working_function{
  .... some working code ......
  do_something();

  }
```

The problem is I get this error:

```
 -[MyDotMMfile working_function] in MyDotMMfile.o
 Symbol(s) not found
 Collect2:ld returned 1 exit status
```

This questioned has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005975/ld-returned-1-exit-status) elsewhere, but the response doesn't seem relevant to my situation. I'm working in XCode and have stopped running my app, rebuilt it and still get the same error. Since I'm new to programming I have a feeling it has to do with how I'm calling my C functions.

Any help?

---

**EDIT 1**

If anyone is feeling so altruistic they may [download the actually files here](http://ericbrotto.com/temporary/Files.zip).

Comment: Show the working_function declaration please. It should be the Objective-C class function by the way

Comment: I'm in middle of posting the entire code. Please give me a moment :)

Comment: @Andrew Please see my first Edit.

Comment: try to call something from math.h to determine if your problem rely upon c or objective-c. And also is it a compiler or linker error ?

Comment: The Build fails, but I believe this type of error is inherently a linker error, no?

Comment: I've called a math function and there doesn't seem to be a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: `C` language has no `class` concept !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to figure out the problem. It had to do with a missing file. The solution I used [I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1/4566804#4566804).

Answer (score 7):

The `.mm` file is looking to call a mangled version of the function name. You need either `__BEGIN_DECLS` and `__END_DECLS` around the C function declarations seen by the C++-compiled file, or you need to do the equivalent yourself. The idea is to mark those function declarations as `extern "C"` when seen by an (Obj-)C++ compiler, but not when seen by any other sort of compiler.